# Alien awakened by the atmosphere in archeological excavation?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember having watched a movie, probably from the late 70's, 80's or early 90's, in which a crew of archeologists were digging up a location off planet earth. They found a set of certain ruins which had a pretty mural depicting an alien form of life... but ALAS! this mural was actually an alien who came back to life, once getting into contact with the atmosphere. The alien obviously went for breakfast taking the excavation crew one by one.

One of the movie gadgets I remember is them having some drills that worked like guns (shoot the drill bit into the wall, go boom), and actually one of the characters is killed because he or she shoots themselves in the head with that drill.

It's been like 25 years since I saw it on tv, hope you guys can help me find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did the humans need to wear helmeted space suits on that planet or did it have a breathable atmosphere?

Comment: they needed a suit, if memory serves, this suit was yellow

Comment: I vaguely recall the "alien as mural" as part of a science fiction short story. Perhaps it got adapted?

Comment: How that alien looked like?

Answer (score 4):

It could be [**Inseminoid**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084090/)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inseminoid

> On a freezing planet, a team of 12 Xeno Project **archaeologists and
> scientists are excavating the ruins of an ancient civilisation**. They
> discover a cave system **containing wall markings** and crystals of
> unknown origin. During a survey, a mysterious explosion cripples
> photographer Dean White and injures Ricky Williams.
>
> A crystal sample begins to pulsate, causing the intelligence to take
> control of Ricky through a wound on his arm. In his delusional state,
> he is compelled to leave the team's base and go back into the caves.
> He throws Gail into a pile of twisted metal, damaging her
> environmental suit and trapping her foot. Desperate to free herself,
> Gail removes her helmet and tries to amputate her foot with a
> chainsaw, but instead freezes to death in the planet's toxic
> atmosphere. Documentation officer Kate Carson **shoots Ricky with a
> harpoon gun** before he opens the airlock and evacuates all of the
> base's air.

The wall:
[image]

Alien comes to life:
[image]

[Full movie (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzNe4RFWcmw&t=320s)

Comment: I had already tried with inseminoid, but it wasnt the one. In this one, the part of the drills is not present :/

Comment: @JuanPabloFajardoRamírez could be that scene https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzNe4RFWcmw&t=4002s (harpoon handgun is used).